# Can a poor client VPN connection corrupt a database?

Tags: vpn, tcp, pptp

We have a small office with one server and one client that connects to the server’s database for the Sage 300 accounting software. The server is also being used as a workstation for the Sage 300 software. I want the person who uses the server was a workstation to be able to connect to the server from home so I figured the best way to do this would be to install the Sage 300 client software on the home computer, connect the computer to the office via VPN and then open the database that is on the server in the Sage 300 client software.

According to the Sage technical support staff, this is not recommended because VPN connections are unreliable and can lead to data corruption on the database if there is a problem with the VPN connection.

How true is this? I figured that since PPTP uses TCP there should be no data corruption. Am I wrong about this?

What is the best way to connect to the server remotely without risking data corruption if the VPN fails? I was thinking that the computer from home can connect to the SonicWall router through VPN and then connect to the server through remote desktop in which case no data will actually be stored on the client computer at home. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Only if it's MySql or Access ;D

Answer (score 3):

If an unreliable connection can cause database corruption, then the problem isn't the connection but that the software is poorly designed.

Answer (score 0):

Sage is not really a multi-user system. Yes, you could end up with a corrupt database running the client remotely from where the data is stored. Given the context in which I would expect to find Sage, I suspect that upgrading to a more capable system may not be an option (and software recommendations are off topic here). But you can avoid the issue by running the client where the data is and exporting the display via RDP, Citric, VNC or NoMachine.